# How to set kerberos weblogic configuration

Tags: java, sql-server, server, weblogic, kerberos

Where do I need to put this information?

```
grant codeBase "file:/WL_HOME/server/lib/-" { permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.DDTEK-JDBC"; permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAs" permission javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission "krbtgt/your_realm@your_realm", "initiate"; permission javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission "MSSQLSvc/db_hostname:SQLServer_port@your_realm", "initiate
```

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any

Answer (score 0):

You place this information inside the weblogic.policy file.  Default path looks something like $WL_HOME/weblogic$/server/lib/weblogic.policy on Linux or WL_HOME\server\lib\weblogic.policy on Windows.

You will need to generate a keytab file containing the shared secret key of the service.  Place the keytab file into the domain directory of your Oracle WebLogic Server.  This reference provides a complete step by step of what you should do:  [How To Configure Browser-based SSO with Kerberos/SPNEGO and Oracle WebLogic Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/weblogic-sso-kerberos-1619890.html)

Comment: i need to use keytab for database authorization in webloigc. my application should read dabase configuration from jndi specified in weblogic data. can u please guide me what exaclty need to be done for same.

Comment: What you just asked was a new, separate question.  I just updated the answer to reflect the new information.  What you do is generate a keytab file containing the shared secret key of the service. Place the keytab file into the domain directory of your Oracle WebLogic Server.  Please see update above.